# How to align all the table cells inside the collapsed row with the cells in expandable row?

Tags: css, typescript, html-table, material-ui

I'm trying to create a table with expandable/collapsible rows. The head row with a taskID
and first taskAction is rendered as Expandable row with `<IconButton>`. The other taskActions of the same taskID (collapsible rows) are rendered inside the `<Collapse>` container. While running the component with mock data, the cells inside the collapse are not properly aligned with the head row.

Screenshot of the table body with head rows:

[image: Screenshot of the table body with head rows]

Screenshot of misaligned collapsible rows

[image: Screenshot of misaligned collapsible rows]

Code for the table:

```js
function Task(props: { task: taskProps }) {
  const { task } = props;
  console.log(task);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <>  
    {task.tasksActions.map((taskAction, index) => {
        if(index == 0){
          return(
          <TableRow key={index}>
            <TableCell>
                <IconButton
                    aria-label="expand row"
                    size="small"
                    onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
                >
                    {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
                </IconButton>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                {task.taskId}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
                {taskAction.actionId}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>{taskAction.templateStepId}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{taskAction.templateStepName}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>100</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{taskAction.startedAt}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{taskAction.endedAt}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{taskAction.status}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
          );
        }
        else {
          return(
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={9}>
              <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <TableCell>{' '}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                  {task.taskId}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                  {taskAction.actionId}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{taskAction.templateStepId}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{taskAction.templateStepName}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>100</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{taskAction.startedAt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{taskAction.endedAt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{taskAction.status}</TableCell>
            </Collapse>
            </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          );
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
}
    
export const MetricsTable = () => {
      return (
        <TableContainer component={Card}>
          <Table aria-label="collapsible table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell key={'headCol0'}>{" "}</TableCell>
                <TableCell key={'headCol1'}>ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell key={'headCol2'}>ACTION</TableCell>
                <TableCell key={'headCol3'}>TITLE</TableCell>
                <TableCell key={'headCol4'}>DESCRIPTION</TableCell>
                <TableCell key={'headCol5'}>DURATION</TableCell>
                <TableCell key={'headCol6'}>START</TableCell>
                <TableCell key={'headCol7'}>END</TableCell>
                <TableCell key={'headCol8'}>STATUS</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {jsonData.map((task) => (
                <Task key={task.taskId} task={task} />
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      );
    };
```

I would appreciate the help with aligning the cells uniformly.

Comment: did you try to add `table-layout: fixed;` ?

Comment: Yes, still doesn't work.